# Calculate number of rows with current month & year in Google Sheets or Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have one row filled with dates in the format MM/dd/yyyy (with header row), such as:

```
DATES
5/12/2015
4/12/2012
5/7/2015
5/7/2014
```

I would like to count the number of rows which match the current month & year. In the example above, the result would obviously be two (when it's May 2015).

Is this possible to achieve this result using a function? Preferably using Google Spreadsheet, but Excel is also fine.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I would prefer a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google sheets you can use

```
=COUNT(FILTER(A:A,MONTH(A:A) = MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(A:A)=YEAR(TODAY())))
```

Where **A:A** is the column with your dates

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the header row, is there a way say "all other rows than the header row in column A" without using fixed row numbers?

Comment: You can do it with header row as well, this function will still work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1** through **A20**

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A1:A20)=MONTH(TODAY()))*(YEAR(A1:A20)=YEAR(TODAY())))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, pretty clever! I forgot to add there is a header row but that's not an issue with your answer.

Comment: Ideally, this could be shortened to `=SUMPRODUCT(--(EOMONTH(A1:A4)=EOMONTH(TODAY())))`.  However, `EOMONTH` doesn't support ranges like `MONTH` does.  Do you know of an online reference that shows which Excel functions support ranges in `SUMPRODUCT`?  If not, I might post that as a question.

Comment: @RickHitchcock In Excel 2007 and later versions functions like `EOMONTH`, `WEEKNUM`, `NETWORKDAYS` (ex ATP functions) support **arrays** but not ranges, but you can convert a range to an array by using a "co-ercer" so this works: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(EOMONTH(A1:A4+0,0)=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))` - where the +0 is the "co-ercer" to convert to an array

Comment: @barryhoudini, that's perfect.  I was preparing this question as a new post, and I think your answer would be useful to many people.  If I post the question, would you answer it so I can accept it?

Comment: No problem - Note that it's not SUMPRODUCT here that restricts, it's simply the functions themselves

Comment: Another option with `SUMPRODUCT`, which works in Excel 2003 and earlier versions - `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4-DAY(A1:A4)=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())))`

Comment: Cool.  Done:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194275/allow-ranges-in-any-excel-formula

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNTIFS` like this

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1)`

That works equally well in Excel or google sheets, for the whole column and will ignore the header row