# Allow ranges in any Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, some functions accept ranges, which can be used with `SUMPRODUCT` and other array functions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MONTH(A1:A4) ...)       <-- no problem
```

Other functions do *not*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(EOMONTH(A1:A4, 0) ...)  <-- ERROR
```

Is there a way to force functions like `EOMONTH` to work with ranges?

Comment: No, the functions parameters are fixed, as documented by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197615.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the ex `"Analysis ToolPak"` functions like `EOMONTH`, `WORKDAY`, `NETWORKDAYS`, `WEEKNUM` etc. will accept arrays in `Excel 2007` or later - so you can use a "co-ercer" like +0 or *1 to change an array to a range, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM(A1:A10+0)=1))`

That will give you a count of how many of the dates in `A1:A10` are in week 1 (as defined by `WEEKNUM`) - without the +0 it doesn't work.

There are other functions - like `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` which can't easily output arrays - those **can't** be co-erced in the same way

Comment: That's perfect and it greatly simplifies this type of problem.  Thanks!