# Calculate number of rows with current month & year in Google Sheets or Excel, when dates are in ISO format

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have one column filled with dates in ISO format (with header row), such as:

```
DATES
2015-05-13 12:46:41
2015-03-19 11:50:13
```

I would like to count the number of rows which match the current month & year. In the example above, the result would obviously be one (when it's May 2015).

Is this possible to achieve this result using a function in Google Spreadsheet?

Same question without ISO date can be found at:

[Calculate number of rows with current month & year in Google Sheets or Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188741/calculate-number-of-rows-with-current-month-year-in-google-sheets-or-excel)

Comment: I assume you tried those solutions but they didn't work? If the values are true date/time values the format (i.e. the way it's displayed) shouldn't stop those formulas from working - if they don't work that probably means you have text values, not dates - try converting by doing this: `Select Date Column > Data > Text to columns > Finish`

Comment: These dates are actually pushed to the spreadsheet by Zapier. Whenever a new date is pushed via the API I would like the counter to be increased. It seems that they indeed are text, but I couldn't find a way to automatically treat them as dates.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer with a formula you can use on text formatted dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are text values, as per my comment, then the suggested formulas in the link won't work - either convert as suggested or you can use this formula to count text values that represent the current month

`=COUNTIF(A:A,TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-")&"*")`

or avoiding date formats in text function

`=COUNTIF(A:A,YEAR(TODAY())&"-"&TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"00")&"-*")`

change commas to semi-colons depending on regional settings

Comment: Are you sure the formula is ok? It gives an error in both Google Spreadsheet and Excel

Comment: Are you using Excel or google? You may need to account for regional variations in TEXT function -e.g. "yyyy-mm" might need to change, what are your regional settings?

Comment: I posted another method to avoid date formats in TEXT function

Comment: I'm using Google Spreadsheet, but I also tested with Excel and neither of those formulas work. I can adjust the regional settings of the Spreadsheet as required.

Comment: They work for me - do you get an error, is the formula accepted? You may have to change the commas to semi-colons depending on your region, e.g. with the second version I posted change to `=COUNTIF(A:A;YEAR(TODAY())&"-"&TEXT(MONTH(TODAY());"00")&"-*")`